# Solr Exception: Sort param field can't be found

Tags: solr, ckan

I've been trying to set up CKAN, however I am facing some problems in SOLR.
Everytime I run CKAN, the SOLR log file registers a new event, and that is:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: sort param field can't be found: metadata_modified
```

I am trying to use CKAN for the first time and I have no experience at all, so I have no idea what that log event means, nor how to fix it.

EDIT:
When I reload the core at SOLR, the following is logged:

```
The schema has been upgraded to managed,&#8203; but the non-managed schema schema.xml is still loadable. PLEASE REMOVE THIS FILE.
```

Could anyone help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out the SOLR 6, for some reason, was the problem.
Downgrading to version 5 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are not using CKAN's custom Solr schema. Make sure to go over all points in the [setup documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#setting-up-solr), specially point 2, and to restart jetty afterwards:

```
sudo service restart jetty
```

Comment: Hi amercader, I followed this tutorial here [link] (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-2.5.2-on-Windows-7), and completed every step. I am on a Windows machine, so cant use the link you provided. But I did move the ckan\config\solr\schema.xml to to my server's conf folder. This tutorial I used doesn't mention Jetty, so I didn't install it. Do you have any recommendation or links to guide me for a Windows? Thank you very much!